# Ant not able to locate external jar files. Showing java.lang.NoClassDefFound Error exception

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I am creating a jar file using following target -

```
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">  
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/TargetClass.jar" 
        basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

and I'm trying to execute the jar file using following target -

```
    <target name="runjar">
       <java jar="${jar.dir}/TargetClass.jar" fork="true"/>
     </target>
```

I've used apache poi jar in my TragetClass which is located under D:/Jar directory. While executing it's not able to locate the poi jars and showing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `classpath`. Something like:

```
<property name="poi.jars" value="path to poi jars"/>

<path id="run.classpath">
  <pathelement location="${poi.jars}"/>
</path>

<target name="runjar">
  <java 
    jar="${jar.dir}/TargetClass.jar" 
    fork="true"
   <classpath refid="run.classpath"/>
  />
</target>
```

See [Ant Java Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) for more information.